# Why don't relative imports with AMD work in requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

So, if you have a folder:

```
- demo/js/foo/foo.js
- demo/js/foo/bar/a.js
- demo/js/foo/bar/b.js
```

Then defining an AMD module's as:

```
foo.js: define(['./bar/a.js', './bar/b.js'], function(a, b) { console.log(a, b); });
a.js: define([], function() { return {a:'a'}; });
b.js: define([], function() { return {b:'b'}; });
```

Then if you import the module like this:

```
require(['./foo/foo'], function() { ... }
```

Gives:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3005/demo/foo/bar/a.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3005/demo/foo/bar/b.js"
Error: Script error for: foo/bar/a.js http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
Error: Script error for: foo/bar/b.js http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Why doesn't this work?

I've read some obscure posts in the requirejs forum saying this is 'working as intended' because 'imports are names, they are not relative paths'. ...and that you should resolve this issue using the 'map' function.

...

Right! Well, I won't go in to how obvious this behavior is, or how vastly unhelpful threads like https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/requirejs/relative/requirejs/Zmh7EV5fR2M/4OM-ss5g3DEJ are; let's just get to the point.

How *are* you supposed to make this work?

Obviously if you import an arbitrary module using bower, and it lives in say, js/lib/obscure.js/dist/obscure.js you need to setup your config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        obscure: 'lib/obscure.js/dist/obscure'
    }
});
```

...but this seems to mean that all 'amd importable' modules end up being massive amalgamations of one simple file with *all* the modules in it.

Using baseUrl is not a solution, because, as above, you expect to have multiple isolated 'islands' of javascript which are installed as modules, which 1) need to refer to each other, but 2) also need to be able to refer to their own *internal, relative* modules.

Seems extremely weird.

Once again, how *are* you supposed to make this work in the non-trivial case?

Edit:

Surely you say, you're doing it wrong and just not telling us all the things you're doing. Well, see for yourself. An exact copy of this not working is now here on github: https://github.com/shadowmint/requirejs-example

Comment: have you added baseUrl: '/path/to/js' in require.config ? in your case baseUrl: ' demo/js/foo/' and then include modules like define(['bar/a.js', 'bar/b.js'], f(){})

Comment: That will work for and *only* for foo; obviously if you have more modules that's no use.

Comment: i think what it means  paths in define([path,path]) are not filepaths but have their own sets of rules. they are a "language" of their own.

Comment: You should take a look at Browserify: Unlike RequireJS, its `require` is based on file system paths and it tends to just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative imports do work.

The problem with your code is that you list your module names together with the `.js` extension. You should never specify a module name with the `.js` extension. If you do put the extension, you're essentially telling RequireJS "I already know that the module I want is at the end of the path I'm giving you; don't mess with this path" so your RequireJS configuration won't affect how the path you put in your dependencies is resolved.

Comment: Makes no difference as far as I can tell. Here, I put an exact example of what I'm doing up online, including the change you've suggested: https://github.com/shadowmint/requirejs-example

Comment: In your example you list the dependencies as `bar/a` and `bar/b`. Of course, it won't work because you've removed the initial `./`. Resolving a relative path is not equivalent with "mess[ing] with this path". That's just resolving paths like all URLs that one ever uses to request resources.

Comment: There you go, I've pushed that change too, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: In your question you have `define` in your `foo` module, which is absolutely correct. In your repo you've change it to a `require` call. I've missed that the first time I looked at your repo but yeah, that won't work.